# Application Domain in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, appdomain

I am beginner.I want to study about Application Domain in ASP.NET. Can anyone explain what is it or give me some good link where I can study for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C Brumme has a very comprehensive [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/06/01/51466.aspx) on App Domains

Also see [When would I use an AppDomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786923/when-would-i-use-an-appdomain), [What are app domains used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207053/what-are-app-domains-used-for) and 
[Usage of AppDomain in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665668/usage-of-appdomain-in-c)